# Python rpm module not calling callback with rpm.RPMCALLBACK_INST_OPEN_FILE

Tags: python, embedded-linux, rpm

I have an embedded platform on which I deploy application code using RPMs. Traditionally this was done after the fact on the target platform (i.e. installing rpm via command line on the target platform through a console). To make life easier and simpler (or so I thought), I decided to directly install the RPM onto the target filesystem as part of the build process on the host. I thought to use the Python RPM module and interacting with the RPM database that resides on the target filesystem. Here's what I tried (note that the RPM database location has been modified to point to the database on the target filesystem as opposed to the default on the host):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, rpm

rpmtsCallback_fd = None

def runCallback(reason, amount, total, key, client_data):
    global rpmtsCallback_fd
    print 'callback called with reason' + str(reason)
    if reason == rpm.RPMCALLBACK_INST_OPEN_FILE:
        print "Opening file."
        rpmtsCallback_fd = os.open(key, os.O_RDONLY)
        return rpmtsCallback_fd
    elif reason == rpm.RPMCALLBACK_INST_CLOSE_FILE:
        print "Closing file"
        os.close(rpmtsCallback_fd)

def installPackage(ts):
    ts.initDB()

    fdno = os.open("/home/mbilloo/test_rfs/application.rpm", os.O_RDONLY)
    hdr = ts.hdrFromFdno(fdno)
    os.close(fdno)

    print 'Installing ' + str(hdr['name']) + ' to RFS'
    ts.addInstall(hdr, "/home/mbilloo/test_rfs/application.rpm", 'i')
    unresolved_deps = ts.check()
    if unresolved_deps:
        print "Have unresolved dependencies: %s" % (unresolved_deps,)
        return
    ts.order()
    ts.run(runCallback, 1)

def checkPackage(ts):
    ts.openDB()
    mi = ts.dbMatch()
    print 'size of mi = '+ str(len(mi))

rpm.addMacro("_dbpath", "/home/mbilloo/test_rfs/var/lib/rpm/")
trs = rpm.TransactionSet()
trs.setVSFlags(-1)

installPackage(trs)
checkPackage(trs)
```

After running the above script, the callback is called three times. First, with reason rpm.RPMCALLBACK_TRANS_START, then with reason rpm.RPMCALLBACK_TRANS_PROGRESS, then finally with reason rpm.RPMCALLBACK_TRANS_STOP. According to the instructions here: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s06s04.html, I should be getting a rpm.RPMCALLBACK_INST_OPEN_FILE during the installation, but this never happens.

Finally, when I check to the see the contents of the database (i.e. "checkingPackage") after installing the RPM, I get length 0 match (meaning there is nothing in the database).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out and just posting my observations in case anyone else runs into the same issue. The problem here was that I had an incompatible architecture between the application (ARM) and the underlying RPM module used by the python library (x86_64). I ultimately determined that this is not possible as there will be database issues on the target platform as well, and ended up working around this issue.